# ubuntu-restricted-extras wants to remove over 200 packages. Could this harm the system?

Tags: installation, 12.04, package-management, aptitude

Has anybody installed ubuntu-restricted-extras yet? (You need this for example to encode mp3). When I try to install that, it wants to remove the following packages:

```
# aptitude install ubuntu-restricted-extras 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53{b} 
  libavutil-extra-51{ab} libfaac0{a} libmjpegtools-1.9{a} libquicktime2{a} 
  ubuntu-restricted-extras unrar 
0 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,811 kB of archives. After unpacking 9,558 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavutil-extra-51 : Conflicts: libavutil51 but 4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libavcodec-extra-53 : Conflicts: libavcodec53 but 4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1 is installed.
open: 107; closed: 1554; defer: 43; conflict: 121                              oThe following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Remove the following packages:                                          
1)       bluez-alsa:i386                                                       
2)       glib-networking:i386                                                  
3)       googleearth                                                           
4)       gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3:i386                                        
5)       gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386                                       
6)       gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386                                       
7)       gstreamer0.10-x:i386                                                  
8)       gtk2-engines:i386                                                     
9)       gtk2-engines-murrine:i386                                             
10)      gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386                                              
11)      gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386                                              
12)      gvfs:i386                                                             
13)      gvfs-libs:i386                                                        
14)      ia32-libs                                                             
15)      ia32-libs-multiarch:i386                                              
16)      ibus-gtk:i386                                                         
17)      libaa1:i386                                                           
18)      libacl1:i386                                                          
19)      libao4:i386                                                           
20)      libasn1-8-heimdal:i386                                                
21)      libasound2:i386                                                       
22)      libasound2-plugins:i386                                               
23)      libasyncns0:i386                                                      
24)      libatk1.0-0:i386                                                      
25)      libattr1:i386                                                         
26)      libaudio2:i386                                                        
27)      libaudiofile1:i386                                                    
28)      libavahi-client3:i386                                                 
29)      libavahi-common3:i386                                                 
30)      libavc1394-0:i386                                                     
31)      libavcodec53                                                          
32)      libavutil51                                                           
33)      libbz2-1.0:i386                                                       
34)      libc6:i386                                                            
35)      libcaca0:i386                                                         
36)      libcairo-gobject2:i386                                                
37)      libcairo2:i386                                                        
38)      libcanberra-gtk-module:i386                                           
39)      libcanberra-gtk0:i386                                                 
40)      libcanberra0:i386                                                     
41)      libcap2:i386                                                          
42)      libcapi20-3:i386                                                      
43)      libcdparanoia0:i386                                                   
44)      libcomerr2:i386                                                       
45)      libcroco3:i386                                                        
46)      libcups2:i386                                                         
47)      libcupsimage2:i386                                                    
48)      libcurl3:i386                                                         
49)      libdatrie1:i386                                                       
50)      libdb5.1:i386                                                         
51)      libdbus-1-3:i386                                                      
52)      libdbus-glib-1-2:i386                                                 
53)      libdrm-intel1:i386                                                    
54)      libdrm-nouveau1a:i386                                                 
55)      libdrm-radeon1:i386                                                   
56)      libdrm2:i386                                                          
57)      libdv4:i386                                                           
58)      libelf1:i386                                                          
59)      libesd0:i386                                                          
60)      libexif12:i386                                                        
61)      libexpat1:i386                                                        
62)      libffi6:i386                                                          
63)      libflac8:i386                                                         
64)      libfontconfig1:i386                                                   
65)      libfreetype6:i386                                                     
66)      libgail-common:i386                                                   
67)      libgail18:i386                                                        
68)      libgcc1:i386                                                          
69)      libgconf-2-4:i386                                                     
70)      libgcrypt11:i386                                                      
71)      libgd2-xpm:i386                                                       
72)      libgdbm3:i386                                                         
73)      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386                                               
74)      libgettextpo0:i386                                                    
75)      libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                                                  
76)      libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                                                  
77)      libglapi-mesa:i386                                                    
78)      libglib2.0-0:i386                                                     
79)      libglu1-mesa:i386                                                     
80)      libgnome-keyring0:i386                                                
81)      libgnutls26:i386                                                      
82)      libgomp1:i386                                                         
83)      libgpg-error0:i386                                                    
84)      libgphoto2-2:i386                                                     
85)      libgphoto2-port0:i386                                                 
86)      libgpm2:i386                                                          
87)      libgssapi-krb5-2:i386                                                 
88)      libgssapi3-heimdal:i386                                               
89)      libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386                                  
90)      libgstreamer0.10-0:i386                                               
91)      libgtk2.0-0:i386                                                      
92)      libgudev-1.0-0:i386                                                   
93)      libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386                                              
94)      libheimbase1-heimdal:i386                                             
95)      libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386                                             
96)      libhx509-5-heimdal:i386                                               
97)      libibus-1.0-0:i386                                                    
98)      libice6:i386                                                          
99)      libidn11:i386                                                         
100)     libiec61883-0:i386                                                    
101)     libieee1284-3:i386                                                    
102)     libjack-jackd2-0:i386                                                 
103)     libjasper1:i386                                                       
104)     libjpeg-turbo8:i386                                                   
105)     libjpeg8:i386                                                         
106)     libjson0:i386                                                         
107)     libk5crypto3:i386                                                     
108)     libkeyutils1:i386                                                     
109)     libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386                                               
110)     libkrb5-3:i386                                                        
111)     libkrb5support0:i386                                                  
112)     liblcms1:i386                                                         
113)     libldap-2.4-2:i386                                                    
114)     libllvm3.0:i386                                                       
115)     libltdl7:i386                                                         
116)     libmad0:i386                                                          
117)     libmikmod2:i386                                                       
118)     libmng1:i386                                                          
119)     libmpg123-0:i386                                                      
120)     libmysqlclient18:i386                                                 
121)     libncurses5:i386                                                      
122)     libncursesw5:i386                                                     
123)     libnspr4:i386                                                         
124)     libnss3:i386                                                          
125)     libodbc1:i386                                                         
126)     libogg0:i386                                                          
127)     liboil0.3:i386                                                        
128)     libopenal1:i386                                                       
129)     liborc-0.4-0:i386                                                     
130)     libp11-kit0:i386                                                      
131)     libpango1.0-0:i386                                                    
132)     libpciaccess0:i386                                                    
133)     libpcre3:i386                                                         
134)     libpixman-1-0:i386                                                    
135)     libpng12-0:i386                                                       
136)     libproxy1:i386                                                        
137)     libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386                                          
138)     libpulse0:i386                                                        
139)     libpulsedsp:i386                                                      
140)     libqt4-dbus:i386                                                      
141)     libqt4-declarative:i386                                               
142)     libqt4-designer:i386                                                  
143)     libqt4-network:i386                                                   
144)     libqt4-opengl:i386                                                    
145)     libqt4-qt3support:i386                                                
146)     libqt4-script:i386                                                    
147)     libqt4-scripttools:i386                                               
148)     libqt4-sql:i386                                                       
149)     libqt4-sql-mysql:i386                                                 
150)     libqt4-svg:i386                                                       
151)     libqt4-test:i386                                                      
152)     libqt4-xml:i386                                                       
153)     libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386                                               
154)     libqtcore4:i386                                                       
155)     libqtgui4:i386                                                        
156)     libqtwebkit4:i386                                                     
157)     libraw1394-11:i386                                                    
158)     libroken18-heimdal:i386                                               
159)     librsvg2-2:i386                                                       
160)     librsvg2-common:i386                                                  
161)     librtmp0:i386                                                         
162)     libsamplerate0:i386                                                   
163)     libsane:i386                                                          
164)     libsasl2-2:i386                                                       
165)     libsasl2-modules:i386                                                 
166)     libsdl-image1.2:i386                                                  
167)     libsdl-mixer1.2:i386                                                  
168)     libsdl-net1.2:i386                                                    
169)     libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386                                                  
170)     libsdl1.2debian:i386                                                  
171)     libselinux1:i386                                                      
172)     libshout3:i386                                                        
173)     libslang2:i386                                                        
174)     libsm6:i386                                                           
175)     libsndfile1:i386                                                      
176)     libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386                                               
177)     libsoup2.4-1:i386                                                     
178)     libspeex1:i386                                                        
179)     libspeexdsp1:i386                                                     
180)     libsqlite3-0:i386                                                     
181)     libssl0.9.8:i386                                                      
182)     libssl1.0.0:i386                                                      
183)     libstdc++5:i386                                                       
184)     libstdc++6:i386                                                       
185)     libtag1-vanilla:i386                                                  
186)     libtag1c2a:i386                                                       
187)     libtasn1-3:i386                                                       
188)     libtdb1:i386                                                          
189)     libthai0:i386                                                         
190)     libtheora0:i386                                                       
191)     libtiff4:i386                                                         
192)     libtinfo5:i386                                                        
193)     libudev0:i386                                                         
194)     libunistring0:i386                                                    
195)     libusb-0.1-4:i386                                                     
196)     libuuid1:i386                                                         
197)     libv4l-0:i386                                                         
198)     libv4lconvert0:i386                                                   
199)     libvisual-0.4-0:i386                                                  
200)     libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386                                            
201)     libvorbis0a:i386                                                      
202)     libvorbisenc2:i386                                                    
203)     libvorbisfile3:i386                                                   
204)     libwavpack1:i386                                                      
205)     libwind0-heimdal:i386                                                 
206)     libwrap0:i386                                                         
207)     libx11-6:i386                                                         
208)     libx11-xcb1:i386                                                      
209)     libxau6:i386                                                          
210)     libxaw7:i386                                                          
211)     libxcb-glx0:i386                                                      
212)     libxcb-render0:i386                                                   
213)     libxcb-shm0:i386                                                      
214)     libxcb1:i386                                                          
215)     libxcomposite1:i386                                                   
216)     libxcursor1:i386                                                      
217)     libxdamage1:i386                                                      
218)     libxdmcp6:i386                                                        
219)     libxext6:i386                                                         
220)     libxfixes3:i386                                                       
221)     libxft2:i386                                                          
222)     libxi6:i386                                                           
223)     libxinerama1:i386                                                     
224)     libxml2:i386                                                          
225)     libxmu6:i386                                                          
226)     libxp6:i386                                                           
227)     libxpm4:i386                                                          
228)     libxrandr2:i386                                                       
229)     libxrender1:i386                                                      
230)     libxslt1.1:i386                                                       
231)     libxss1:i386                                                          
232)     libxt6:i386                                                           
233)     libxtst6:i386                                                         
234)     libxv1:i386                                                           
235)     libxxf86vm1:i386                                                      
236)     odbcinst1debian2:i386                                                 
237)     xaw3dg:i386                                                           
238)     zlib1g:i386                                                           

       Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                            
239)     libcanberra-gtk0:i386 recommends libcanberra-gtk-module:i386          
240)     libgphoto2-2:i386 recommends udev:i386 (>= 0.175)                     
241)     libgphoto2-2:i386 recommends libgphoto2-l10n:i386 (>= 2.4.13-1ubuntu1)
242)     libncurses5:i386 recommends libgpm2:i386                              
243)     libncursesw5:i386 recommends libgpm2:i386                             
244)     libslang2:i386 recommends libpng12-0:i386                             
245)     libvisual-0.4-0:i386 recommends libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386            
246)     libqt4-dbus:i386 recommends qdbus:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1)         
247)     libqtgui4:i386 recommends libcups2:i386
```

Some of these packages don't look so unimportant, so I have some doubts to accept this solution. Has anybody installed this packages so far and didn't get any problems?

Comment: Try "sudo apt-get install -f" and see what it says.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say, I'm using 12.04. But the solution with apt-get already worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems very very wrong to me.

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

shows me ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51
  libfaac0 libmjpegtools-1.9 libopenjpeg2 libquicktime2
Suggested packages:
  libfaad0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libavcodec53 libavutil51
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51
  libfaac0 libmjpegtools-1.9 libopenjpeg2 libquicktime2
  ubuntu-restricted-extras
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,733 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,217 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

This looks more like a correct amount of packages.

This is the part you need to fix first:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavutil-extra-51 : Conflicts: libavutil51 but 4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libavcodec-extra-53 : Conflicts: libavcodec53 but 4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1 is installed.
```

and those packages will disappear from the list.

Comment: You are right. Strange, I've never had differences with aptitude and apt. But I will keep it in mind for next time. Anyway, hav done it with apt-get now and it seems to work.

Comment: Aptitude is not made for multiarch ;)

Comment: yes, did not think about that @takkat :D good call

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add that you can consider pressing `n` when asking for the solution and other possible solutions will be shown. Sometimes the best option is not the first one. I even find convenient the way aptitude shows the suggestions. You can press `?` to see all possible commands, like:

```
n: reject the proposed changes and search for another solution
.: move to the next solution
,: move to the previous solution
```